# Python H2O script: TypeErrors at end/closing

Tags: python-3.x, command-line, h2o

The file **h2otest.py** contains a shortened version of code on https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/glm.html:

```
import h2o
h2o.init()
from h2o.estimators.glm import H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator
prostate = h2o.import_file("https://h2o-public-test-data.s3.amazonaws.com/smalldata/prostate/prostate.csv")
prostate['CAPSULE'] = prostate['CAPSULE'].asfactor()
prostate['RACE'] = prostate['RACE'].asfactor()
prostate['DCAPS'] = prostate['DCAPS'].asfactor()
prostate['DPROS'] = prostate['DPROS'].asfactor()
predictors = ["AGE", "RACE", "VOL", "GLEASON"]
response_col = "CAPSULE"
glm_model = H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator(family="binomial", lambda_= 0, compute_p_values=True)
glm_model.train(predictors, response_col, training_frame= prostate)
print('Finished')
```

I run the code on the command line in a Conda environment *pycharm*, where h2o 3.30.1.3 was installed from PyPi. I am using Python 3.8. I get the same error both on my Mac and a Linux server. There is no existing H2O server at start up :

```
(pycharm) $> python h2otest.py
```

The code does it's job, but gives error messages at the end:

```
...
Parse progress: |█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 100%
glm Model Build progress: |███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 100%
Finished
Closing connection _sid_a7a8 at exit
H2O session _sid_a7a8 closed.
Exception ignored in: <function ExprNode.__del__ at 0x7f9ee65f83a0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/geiringesandnes/miniconda3/envs/pycharm/lib/python3.8/site-packages/h2o/expr.py", line 204, in __del__
  File "/Users/geiringesandnes/miniconda3/envs/pycharm/lib/python3.8/site-packages/h2o/expr.py", line 258, in rapids
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
Exception ignored in: <function ExprNode.__del__ at 0x7f9ee65f83a0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/geiringesandnes/miniconda3/envs/pycharm/lib/python3.8/site-packages/h2o/expr.py", line 204, in __del__
  File "/Users/geiringesandnes/miniconda3/envs/pycharm/lib/python3.8/site-packages/h2o/expr.py", line 258, in rapids
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
Exception ignored in: <function ExprNode.__del__ at 0x7f9ee65f83a0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/geiringesandnes/miniconda3/envs/pycharm/lib/python3.8/site-packages/h2o/expr.py", line 204, in __del__
  File "/Users/geiringesandnes/miniconda3/envs/pycharm/lib/python3.8/site-packages/h2o/expr.py", line 258, in rapids
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
Exception ignored in: <function ExprNode.__del__ at 0x7f9ee65f83a0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/geiringesandnes/miniconda3/envs/pycharm/lib/python3.8/site-packages/h2o/expr.py", line 204, in __del__
  File "/Users/geiringesandnes/miniconda3/envs/pycharm/lib/python3.8/site-packages/h2o/expr.py", line 258, in rapids
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

How can I get rid of those error messages?

Comment: Python 3.8 is not yet supported. http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/welcome.html#requirements Have you tried on 3.6?

Comment: Yes, @NeemaMashayekhi, I got rid of the TypeErrors when using python 3.6 instead. Thank you!